# Channels server development cannot migrate

Tags: django, docker, django-channels

I'm following the tutorial to create a CHAT to learn using Channels. In this way I'm following this tutorial : https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html

I have done everything. When I apply the command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get :

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, polls, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Whereas what is expected :

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

And when I run my Channels server developement (ASGI), I go on the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/lobby/  and I still get on my browser's Javascript console the message error :

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/lobby/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I don't know why it is not working. In my settings.py file of the project :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'chat',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Last thing : I have not been able to install Docker because I'm on Windows 10 HOME. Could it be the problem ?

Thank you ,

**EDIT**

I read some other post about **WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/Test/ [127.0.0.1:36769]**.

I see problems with update of Channels. In my case, I have installed Channels with this command :

```
pip install -U channels
```

And then, I have done an update with this commands :

```
$ git clone git@github.com:django/channels.git
$ cd channels
$ <activate your project’s virtual environment>
(environment) $ pip install -e .  # the dot specifies the current repo
```

How can I can this update to check if the problem comes from here ?

Below, is my **consumer.py** file :

## chat/consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

My template file room.html :

```
<!-- chat/templates/chat/room.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="chat-log" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br/>
    <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="100"/><br/>
    <input id="chat-message-submit" type="button" value="Send"/>
</body>
<script>
    var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};

    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var message = data['message'];
        document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (message + '\n');
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
            document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
        }
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
        var messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
        var message = messageInputDom.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message
        }));

        messageInputDom.value = '';
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Root routing configuration :

```
# mysite/routing.py
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        # (http->django views is added by default)
        'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
        chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
        ),
    })
```

And my routing.py file :

```
# chat/routing.py
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>[^/]+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

Comment: Migrations: If you ran it once, it won't run again, so the output seems normal if you have ran it before. Docker has likely nothing to do with it. I run Django locally without docker. Is the server running? did you run `python manage.py runserver` ? Did you try pinging other endpoints to see if the server is running? Also, did you go through the whole tutorial? the first part specifically state that you will get errors because you haven't created a consumer yet, and goes on to create one...

Comment: as far as docker is concerned, from reading the tutorial, they use REDIS in docker, so if you dont have docker you'll need to install Redis locally, https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/

Comment: Thank you @MrE for your response. Sorry, I think my question was not enough clear. In the tutorial I have done everything up to the title **Enable a channel layer**. If I properly understand the tutorial, I should not get the following Javascript error _WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/lobby/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET_ . I can confirm you that I have run the server. I have created a **consumer** (like asking in the tutorial) which should set a websocket...But no. Docker was a last desperate assumption, but as you told, it is not.